# Mostrar contenido un dato especifico a otra pagina en un gridview asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, aplicación-web

Quisiera que me ayuden  realizando en tu GRIDVIEW una lista pero al ultimo hay un ver es decir que cuando selecione quiero 
que se muestre de cada registro en otra pagina .

**mi codigo es este:**

```
   protected void DtgGestiones_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if (this.IsPostBack)
            {
                try
                {
                    DtTab = new DataTable();
                    DtTab = (DataTable)Session["Data"];
                    DtgGestiones.CurrentPageIndex = 0;
                    DtgGestiones.CurrentPageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
                    DtgGestiones.DataSource = DtTab;
                    DtgGestiones.DataBind();

                    //LLenarGrilla();
                }
                catch (Exception Ex)
                {


                }
            }
        }
```

**CODIGO DE MI HTML**

```
<asp:DataGrid ID="DtgGestiones" runat="server" AllowPaging="true" AllowSorting="true" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
                        BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="0" CellSpacing="0" Font-Bold="False" Font-Overline="False" Font-Strikeout="False"
                        HorizontalAlign="Left" PageSize="250" PagerStyle-Mode="NumericPages" HeaderStyle-Font-Bold="true"
                        CssClass="table table-hover table-bordered table-condensed table-striped"
                        Font-Names="Calibri" Font-Size="12px" OnItemCommand="DtgGestiones_ItemCommand" PagerStyle-CssClass="pagGrig" OnPageIndexChanged="DtgGestiones_PageIndexChanged" OnSortCommand="DtgGestiones_SortCommand" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DtgGestiones_SelectedIndexChanged">

                        <Columns> 
                            <asp:BoundColumn DataField="RUBRO" SortExpression="RUBRO" HeaderText="RUBRO" ReadOnly="True">

                            </asp:BoundColumn>
                            <asp:BoundColumn DataField="OFICINA" SortExpression="OFICINA" HeaderText="OFICINA" ReadOnly="true"></asp:BoundColumn>
                            <asp:BoundColumn DataField="USUARIO ATENCION" SortExpression="USUARIO ATENCION" HeaderText="USUARIO ATENCION" ReadOnly="True"></asp:BoundColumn>
                            <asp:BoundColumn DataField="FECHA DE EMISION"  SortExpression="FECHA DE EMISION" HeaderText="FECHA DE EMISION" ReadOnly="True" DataFormatString="{0:dd/MM/yyyy}"></asp:BoundColumn>
                            <asp:BoundColumn DataField="FECHA DE VENCIMIENTO" SortExpression="FECHA DE VENCIMIENTO" HeaderText="FECHA DE VENCIMIENTO" ReadOnly="True" DataFormatString="{0:dd/MM/yyyy}">
                                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" />
                            </asp:BoundColumn>
                            <asp:BoundColumn DataField="MONTO PAGADO" SortExpression="MONTO PAGADO" HeaderText="MONTO PAGADO" ReadOnly="True" DataFormatString="{0:0,0.00}">
                                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" />
                            </asp:BoundColumn>
                            <asp:BoundColumn DataField="NUMERO DE RECIBO" SortExpression="NUMERO DE RECIBO" HeaderText="NUMERO DE RECIBO" ReadOnly="True" >
                                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" />
                            </asp:BoundColumn>
                            <asp:BoundColumn DataField="PAGADO" SortExpression="PAGADO" HeaderText="PAGADO" ReadOnly="True" >
                                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" />
                            </asp:BoundColumn>
                            <asp:BoundColumn DataField="VALIDADO" HeaderText="VALIDADO" ReadOnly="True" sortExpression="VALIDADO" >
                                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" />
                            </asp:BoundColumn>
                            <asp:ButtonColumn CommandName="Gestiones" HeaderText="Gestionar" Text="Ver" >
                                <ItemStyle
                                    Font-Bold="False" Font-Italic="False" Font-Overline="False"
                                    Font-Strikeout="False" Font-Underline="False" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                            </asp:ButtonColumn>
                        </Columns>
                    </asp:DataGrid>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

```
Solucion era agregar una propiedad al gridview :


protected void DtgGestiones_ItemCommand(object source, DataGridCommandEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.CommandName == "Gestiones")
            {
                try
                {
                    DtSet = new DataSet();
                    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ObtenerCadenaConexion());
                    con.Open();

                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SP_BuscarSeguimiento", con);
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    SqlParameter p1 = new SqlParameter("OPT", 2);
                    SqlParameter p2 = new SqlParameter("periodo", "");
                    SqlParameter p3 = new SqlParameter("oficina", "");
                    SqlParameter p4 = new SqlParameter("rubro", e.Item.Cells[1].Text);

                    cmd.Parameters.Add(p1);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(p2);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(p3);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(p4);



                    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                    da.Fill(dt);
                    DtgVerGestiones.DataSource = dt;
                    DtgVerGestiones.Visible = true;
                    DtgVerGestiones.DataBind();

                    con.Close();





                }
                catch (Exception Ex)
                {
                    // DvError.Visible = true;
                    Session["13"] = Ex.Message;
                }
            }
        }
```